# MVC3 localization code generator

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, localization, resx

I am trying to add two localization resource files into my MVC3 App_GlobalResources.

I add Global.resx and then Gloabl.fr.resx. However, only the first one generates code in .designer.cs. The second one just generate an empty file.

Can anybody help me out?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how its supposed to work. The .designer.cs class is a strongly typed class so that you can type.

@Global.mystring and it will return a localised (depending on the UICulture) string.

The designer file doesn't actually contain the localised strings, it just contains a bunch of properties which (in turn) return the localised string.. this is why you wouldn't need more than one class.

Perhaps you are trying to find a way of retrieving the resources for different cultures e.g. fr?

You need to set the UICulture to "fr". Either manually or by setting the following element in the web config:

```
<globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto"/>
```

This would do it automatically based on your browser settings